# Where to place non-app assets in a Meteor project to avoid bundling?

Tags: meteor

Per the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), I'm trying to determine which special folder to place non-app assets (ex. Photoshop design PSDs) in, so that they still get checked into source control but don't get wrapped into the eventual client or server payloads.

It feels 'wrong' to use `tests/` for this purpose but the docs suggest it has the desired behavior. Can `private/` be used similarly, or will its contents always get added to the server bundle regardless of whether your app code registers any Assets? (Or is there a better place altogether to put such files?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a project structure like this:

```
/YourMeteorProject
    /YourPSDFiles
       file1.psd
       file2.psd
       ...
    /YourMeteorApp
       /.meteor
       /client
       /server
       ...
```

You can launch your meteor app from within /YourMeteorApp.  Files that are not part of your application, such as your PSD files, are kept outside of the application.

Comment: Great point, I was overcomplicating the problem by worrying about the special folders. Much easier to restructure the repo instead :)